# I dont know where the syntax error is, it says the error is on the name of the version of python

Tags: python-3.x

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGsDC.png)
I see no syntax error even though the message is there when I press execute. Also, is it normal for it to be issued immediately when I enter it?
Sorry, its my first question, I am new here.

```
>>> a=5

>>> b=10

>>> x=a+b

>>> print("task:", a, "+", b)
task: 5 + 10

>>> print("please enter a number") 

>>> z=input()

>>> number = int(z)
15

>>> print("your input", z)
your input 15
>>>
>>> print("your input", x)
your input 15`
```

Comment: on which line are you getting this error. Your statements are getting executed correctly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are running something copied and pasted from a Shell on an IDLE script file.
Delete everything and paste this:

```
a=5
b=10
x=a+b
print("task:", a, "+", b)
print("please enter a number") 
z=input()
number = int(z)
print("your input", z)
print("your input", x)
```

Then run (press F5 and select "Ok" to save). That should solve the issue!

Please note that the window from where you took the screenshot is the IDLE and the window that pops up is the Shell. You write the code in the IDLE and watch it run in the Shell *OR* you can write and run your code in-line in the Shell.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax error is because you are trying to concatenate number and string.
Do this

```
print("your input", str(x))
```

Comment: didnt worked, i checked the example of the code in my book, and it should be right.

Comment: Where exactly is the error at? Which line gives you error?

Comment: the first line is red marked, its in my screenshot, did u see my link?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. Try to uninstall python and reinstall it.

Comment: This is not the problem as print function accepts integers, as long as separated from other dtypes by a comma. Please refer to my answer to see what is the problem.